# Can't get overlay to resize fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I've been able to get the canvas to resize, and also include touch events. But for some reason, I can't get the overlay image to fill the canvas.

I'm using the [recommended code from fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#setOverlayImage)

```
canvas.setOverlayImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/jail_cell_bars.png', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    width: width,
    height: height,
    // Needed to position overlayImage at 0/0
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
  });
```

My [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crtive/rhug8xov/) has a fair bit of code, as I'm not sure if it's the resizer or touch events that might be causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your fiddle stems from the fact that in Fabric.js, setting `width` and `height` don't scale an image to the given values but rather set the dimensions of the `fabric.Image` *container*. What you need to do is call `canvas.overlayImage.scaleToWidth(width)` (or `.scaleToHeight(height)`) in the `setOverlayImage()`'s callback, so that the image would actually be scaled to cover the whole canvas:

```js
//Image Edit
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  preserveObjectStacking: true
});

canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
canvas.setHeight(window.innerWidth);
fabric.Image.fromURL("https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg", function(img) {
  img.scale(0.5).set({
    left: 150,
    top: 150,
    angle: 0
  });
  canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
});

var info = document.getElementById('info');




function resize() {
  var canvasSizer = document.getElementById("imageEditor");
  var canvasScaleFactor = canvasSizer.offsetWidth / 525;
  var width = canvasSizer.offsetWidth;
  var height = canvasSizer.offsetHeight;
  var ratio = canvas.getWidth() / canvas.getHeight();
  if ((width / height) > ratio) {
    width = height * ratio;
  } else {
    height = width / ratio;
  }
  var scale = width / canvas.getWidth();
  var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
  zoom *= scale;
  canvas.setDimensions({
    width: width,
    height: height
  });
  canvas.setViewportTransform([zoom, 0, 0, zoom, 0, 0])
  canvas.setOverlayImage('https://i.imgur.com/1CURvP5.png', function() {
    canvas.overlayImage && canvas.overlayImage.scaleToWidth(width)
    canvas.renderAll()
  }, {
    // Needed to position overlayImage at 0/0
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', resize, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);

var textObj = new fabric.IText("Test Text", {
  fontSize: 22,
  top: 362.5,
  left: 262.5,
  hasControls: true,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  centeredrotation: true,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});
canvas.add(textObj);
canvas.renderAll();

canvas.on({
  'touch:gesture': function() {
    var text = document.createTextNode(' Gesture ');
    info.insertBefore(text, info.firstChild);
  },
  'touch:drag': function() {
    var text = document.createTextNode(' Dragging ');
    info.insertBefore(text, info.firstChild);
  },
  'touch:orientation': function() {
    var text = document.createTextNode(' Orientation ');
    info.insertBefore(text, info.firstChild);
  },
  'touch:shake': function() {
    var text = document.createTextNode(' Shaking ');
    info.insertBefore(text, info.firstChild);
  },
  'touch:longpress': function() {
    var text = document.createTextNode(' Longpress ');
    info.insertBefore(text, info.firstChild);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.4/fabric.js"></script>


<div id="imageEditor">
  <div class="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

(I had to re-upload the *jail_cell_bars.png* image elsewhere because the original hosting was not cooperating)

Comment: Amazing thanks @shkaper! One step closer to my final project! Now I just need to smooth out the undo, redo feature. Will need to find some sort of layer lock.